# Use nextjs routing outside react hooks in regular javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I have a NextJS app. I want to add a function that can redirect to any page using nextjs routing.

For example, after finishing signup I want to redirect to a certain page.

If I create this function (reusable everywhere) :

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const goTo = (href) => {
  const router = useRouter()
  router.push(href)
}
```

I want to add this to my signup Logic, the problem is that I break React Hooks rules :

> react-dom.development.js?ac89:14906 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
>    See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

And effectively `useRouter` is a React Hook, and I'm trying to call it outside a React function, as stipulated here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html it will not work.

How can I then have a routing solution for NextJS to be callable in regular Javascript ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So If you're using purely React.js (without Next.js on top of it), you can simple do it this way:

```
 Import React from 'react' 

export const handleRoutes = (url) => {
 const history = React.useHistory() 
return history.push(url)
```

}

Then You'd import this regular js function in any of your react files, like this:

```
import { handleRoutes } from 'fileName.js'

<button onClick={()  => handleRoutes("/routeToBeRedirectedTo")}> Click to redirect </button>
```

However when using Nextjs I'm not sure that the above way would work. My personal method would be simply implementing this function (in a utility.js file):

```
export const handleRedirect = (router, url) => {
 return router.push(url)}
```

Then just importing the function & useRouter hook in the file you want:

```
import { handleRedirect } from "./utility.js"
import { useRouter } from "next/router" 

const router = useRouter
```

Then inside your JSX return statement:

```
<button onClick={()  => handleRedirect(router, "/routeToBeRedirectedTo")}> Click to redirect </button>
```

And if it's a redirect after sign in/sign up, just simply useEffect like so:

```
// depends if you're storing your user credentials in your local storage or cookies, this example below would be if your User credentials are stored in localstorage 
const user = JSON.parse(localstorage.getItem("user"))

UseEffect(() => {
 if (user) return handleRedirect(router, "/routeToBeRedirectedTo")
}, [user])
```